# Meaning of "to hand over to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Telling the Centre that  it is an act of “basic fairness ,” the Supreme Court on  Monday directed it to hand over to deposed Arunachal Pradesh Chief Minister NabamTuki documents, equipment, data, and personal papers seized  from the offices and residences  of Mr. Tuki and his ministers  on the orders of Governor  J.P. Rajkhowa, hours after  emergency was declared in  the State on Republic Day.

In this passage I am unable to understand to whom "Centre" will give the documents - the minister, or the court?

Comment: The "centre" must give the documents etc. to Mr Tuki. That's the only way this passage can be read.

Comment: I agree: `to hand over to deposed Arunachal Pradesh Chief Minister NabamTuki documents`  --> The court tells you to hand over documents to deposed....

Answer (score 1):

The indirect object, introduced by "to" is "deposed ArunachalPradesh Chief Minister NabamTuki".

"Deposed ArunachalPradesh Chief Minister" is a modifier within that NP (noun phrase).

Comment: Sir your timing in this site, so I can ask more question like this

Comment: Sorry, @ManishRai, I don't know what "your timing in this site" means. Certainly you can ask more questions, but they may be better suited to English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed recipient of the data is "*deposed Arunachal Pradesh Chief Minister Nabam Tuki*".

Here, *Arunachal Pradesh* is a state in India. The *Arunachal Pradesh Chief Minister* is the Chief Minister of Arunachal Pradesh. He happens to have been deposed, so he is referred to as *deposed Arunachal Pradesh Chief Minister*.
This phrase appears before the man's name *Nabam Tuki* and together these form one large noun phrase.

One reason that it is difficult to understand who is getting what here, is that the sentence uses what is known as *heavy noun phrase shift*.

Consider the following:

- Give to Brenda it.

This sentence is very odd because we would expect the following:

- Give it to Brenda.

We expect to see the prepositional phrase *to Brenda* occurring after the Object *it*. But in the odd, if not ungrammatical, example further above, we see the prepositional Complement  occurring before the Object.

However, when an Object is very *heavy*, in other words very long, this makes it acceptable - if not preferable - to shift the object noun phrase to the end of the clause:

- Give to Brenda [all the data which you've collected from the various participants since the project began].

Because of the weight of the Object here this sentence is as good as, if not preferable to:

- Give  [all the data which you've collected from the various participants since the project began] to Brenda.

In the Original Posters sentence, the Object is very long indeed which is why we see it occurring after the the prepositional phrase. The Direct Object is:

- documents, equipment, data, and personal papers seized from the offices and residences of Mr. Tuki and his ministers on the orders of Governor J.P. Rajkhowa, hours after emergency was declared in the State on Republic Day

That's a very weighty Direct Object indeed. If we just had the Head nouns from each noun phrase we would expect these phrases to be the other way round:

- ... hand over [the data] [to Tuki].

This would be preferable to:

- ... hand over [to Tuki] [the data].

Comment: Is this right - - - - give to me  it

Comment: @ManishRai No, because *it* isn't long enough  to change its position in the sentence. :)

Comment: Sir your timing in this  site,  so I can ask more question like this

Comment: @ManishRai It's a bit random,   but if you ask a question, I'll get back to you eventually :)